# uiwebview reload/append data if scrolling occurs at the top or at the bottom

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, scroll, reload

i am using uiwebview to render data as html in my iphone application. i want to refresh the data if user is scrolling at the top of the view and i want to append  the next page to the current page if the user is scrolling at the bottom of of the view.

and also during reload or fetching data i would like to freeze the screen and show a loading animation in the space between scroll layer and data render layer.

i am using TapDetectingWindow to handle the scroll position but never i get negative value for top scrolling and nor bigger value for bottom scrolling.

http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Boreas got right, but first you need a reference for the UIScrollView embedded in the UIWebView, then work along with it.

```
for(id eachSubview in [webView subviews])
        if ([eachSubview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
            scrollView = eachSubview;
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

in UIScrollViewDelegate and then get the currentOffset of the scrollview?